# Set Date Field with Format into Lead SDK CRM Object

Tags: date, datetime, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

i'm trying to set bithday date into lead entity crm sdk.

```cs
var tmplead = new myservice.lead { 
                emailaddress1 = "dum@dum.com", firstname = "Dany Paredes" , 
                new_fechadenacimiento = 
                  Convert.ToDateTime("01/02/1973",new CultureInfo("es-ES")) 
              };
```

but tmplead.new_fechanacimiento remove one day left to date, how i can set a culture and use exact date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add `ToLocalTime()` after you convert the date, CRM 2011 keeps the date in UTC format.

```cs
var tmplead = new myservice.lead {
    emailaddress1 = "dum@dum.com",
    firstname = "Dany Paredes" ,
    new_fechadenacimiento = 
      Convert.ToDateTime("01/02/1973",new CultureInfo("es-ES")).ToLocalTime()
};
```